# HTML page is refreshing after clicking on submit button with onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a form in this **index.html** page with an Ajax script, on clicking the **submit** button it should just display "Authentification succeeded" or not, if the user is in the database, it works but when I hit submit it displays the message for only one second. How can I keep the message displayed?
Here's the **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Accueil</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        h1 {
            color:red;
        }
    </style>
        <script  language="javascript">
    function chargement()
    {
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET','verif.php?email='+email+'&password='+password,true);
        x.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if ((x.readyState == 4 ) && (x.status == 200))
            {
                document.getElementById('res').innerHTML= x.responseText;
            }
        }
        x.send();
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Bienvenu(e) à Affariyet.tn </h1>
    <table>
    <form action="index.html" method="GET">
        <tr>
        <td>Email :</td>
        <td> <input type="text" id ="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Votre Email"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Mot De Passe : </td>
        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Votre Mot De Passe"><br></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="auth" value="S'authentifier" onclick="chargement()">
            <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Annuler">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><div id="res"> </div></td>
        </tr>
    </form>

     </table>


</body>
</html>
```

And this is the PHP file that has the verification function :

```
<?php 
include 'config.php';
class main
{
    public $conn; 
    function __construct()
    {
        $c=new config();
        $this->conn=$c->connexion();
    }
    function verif($conn,$email,$password)
    {
        $req="SELECT `Email`,`Password` FROM utilisateur WHERE `Email`='$email' AND `Password`='$password' ";
        $res=$conn->query($req);
        return $res->RowCount();
    }
}

$m=new main();

$email=$_GET['email'];
$password=$_GET['password'];
$resultat=$m->verif($m->conn,$email,$password);
if($resultat==0)
{
    echo '<h4 style="color:red;"> Email ou mot de passe erroné</h4>';
}
else
{
    echo '<h4 style="color:green;">Authentification réussie. Accéder à la <a href=produit.php>Liste des produits</a></h4>';
}


 ?>
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. Currently the page reloads?

Comment: ... also, you _relly_ should escape input, as as it is now, it's vulnerable to mysql injection. Look for `mysql_escape` and/or `prepared statement`s (preffered).

Comment: I'm open to way more than that hahah, I'm just testing out Ajax, and yes the page reloads, I just want it to keep diplaying the message without reloading? and how do I prevent sql injections?

Comment: not to mention sending passwords over a GET. *Not safe*.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php.

Comment: I'm not posting this online or anything and using GET for passwords is stupid I know haha but again I'm just starting to test ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue comes from that, when you submit:

1. you execute the `chargement()` function as stated by the `onclick` attribute, and it works
2. but since your button has `type="submit"` its default behaviour is to submit the form: then the `action="index.php"` is executed, so reloading the page, which obviously doesn't not include what you'd just put into the `res` div

To avoid this (i.e work without reloading the page) you can use two ways:

- one is to prevent default action, either as already proposed by @anhkzet (
  but in your case it can't work "as is"; look at it's answer's edit), or by adding `event` as argument to your `chargement()` function, then including `event.preventDefault;` before it ends
- more simply you can change your `<input type="submit"...>` into `<button type=button"...>`: this way the form is not submitted at all.

---

EDIT in response to the supplemental question added by the OP in its comment below.

In order to use `POST` rather than `GET` you can merely substitute the desired method in your `XMLHttpRequest.open()` function.

I guess that you ask it because you're incertain about how to pass `POST` data in this case.
In fact there is no place in the method for an argument that would contain such data, but it doesn't matter: like with the `<form>` tag you can at once use `POST` method *and* keep query parameters attached to the url.

Comment: Thank you so much!
EDIT: do you know how can I use POST method instead of GET?

Comment: @Hadh reagarding your last question, look at my edit.

Comment: `which works with jQuery while you're using pure JS` - it _works_ with pure JS, I just forgot, that when handler specified in tag's attribute, you must explicitly specify, that you want use return value of substituted code as handler return value (i.e., `onclick="return handler()"`), 'cause by default handler attribute value if just treated as subject for `eval()`, without consideration of resulting return value. When you assigning handler directly in script (`...forms[0].onsubmit = handler;`, or via `addEventListener()`) - it will work `out of the box` without extra wrapping.

Comment: @ankhzet You're right, I initially reacted too quickly. Thanks for correcting me, I edited my answer.

Comment: also `preventDefault()` wouldn't work, as it only prevents `bubbling` - event won't fire another attached handlers, but stil wouldn't prevent default behaviour of element reaction to event. So, other `onclick`'ed and `addEventListener()`'ed handlers wouldn't be called, but form would be submitted.

Comment: @ankhzet No, `preventDefault()` IS the way to avoid submit (the default action). You confused with `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: Not quite, I just forget (_duh! again!_), that event object also must be passed explicitly, and was stumbled, when `preventDefault()` doesn't worked in test snippet...

Answer (score 2):

Inputs with type `submit` are meant to send data in form to server. To prevent default behaviour of submit button add `return false;` at the end of `chargement()` handler.

---

*Ok, apparantly, I forgot 'bout `return` statement inside attribute...*

Either:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return chargement()" />
```

... and add `return false` to the end of `chargement` method.

...or just

```
<input type="submit" onclick="chargement(); return false;" />
```

Both should work.

Comment: It didn't change anything, could you explain a little more?